# why does 'VERB+ing' come after 'to' in this context?

Tags: infinitives, verb-forms, syntax

I am studying for the TOEFL iBT and I have this sample introduction to an independent writing section:

> Although some people prefer to work alone, I believe it is much better to work in teams. The benefits for working in teams vastly exceed the convenience of working alone. In my opinion, there are two main advantages **to working** in teams over working alone.

My question: why does *working* come after *to*? I have been taught that after *to* we must use the "zero verb" or "general" form of the verb.

Comment: Following the research by FumbleFingers, which shows the quoted passage to have been written by a non-native speaker, I'm going to vote to close this as Too Localised.

Comment: And please do not be discouraged if it is closed; it was a sound, interesting question, it just happened to be based on a false premise, that your quote represented Standard English. Welcome to ELL! Come again soon!

Comment: *Leave Open.*  Although I agree *"The benefits for working"* is strange, the sentence in question (*"In my opinion..."*) is, as far as I can tell, Standard English.  This seems like a reasonable question for ELL.

Comment: "benefits of working in..." is surely the correct form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There **is** an error here, but it is not what you think it is.

*To* in this case is not the ‘infinitive marker’, which sits in front of an infinitive (what you call the ‘verb-zero or –general’), but the ordinary preposition *to*, which may very well take a gerund (the *-ing* form acting as a noun) as its object.

Unfortunately, it’s the **wrong** preposition—or at least it used to be.

When I was young, fifty years ago, one said there is an advantage *in* or *of* this that or the other. This was distinct from the advantage *to* the person who received the benefit. Your example would have been written (with the *to* phrase added) as:

> There are two main advantages **to** many employees **in** working in teams over working alone.

In colloquial use, however, the construction with *to* instead of *in* has been growing more and more common for the past three quarters of a century; and I have no doubt that it will eventually be accepted in formal use, if it has not been already. Here's a Google Ngram:

[image: advantage to having, advantage in having]

But I recommend that you maintain the distinction. That way you will never raise anybody's eyebrows, not even those of old fogeys like me; and you will avoid the repetition if you ever have to say something like:

> <sup>?</sup>There is an advantage **to** you **to** maintaining the distinction.

That's awkward. It's much more graceful to say

> There is an advantage **to** you **in** maintaining the distinction.

---

<sup>?</sup> *marks an utterance as marginally or only possibly acceptable*

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion on the relative merits of *benefits **of** working* as opposed to *benefits **to** working*, but what I find absolutely appalling about OP's passage is that not only has the writer has used **for** the first time (which is *never* valid, imho). He's followed that with **of** the second time, and **to** for the final one. I could even accept **in** if it were used consistently, but this writer doesn't seem to be able to remember which preposition he used for the same context, *earlier in the same sentence*. "Ye gods and little fishes!", as we used to say.

Comment: Ditto. I've left my first comment, because unless I missed it, you didn't specifically point out the "triple inconsistency".